Reading data from file loaded into compiler memory in Keil MDK v7
#include <stdint.h> // Standard integer types

int main(void) {
    volatile uint8_t *inputImageData = (volatile uint8_t*)0x40000000;
    volatile uint8_t *outputGrayscaleData = (volatile uint8_t*)0x50000000;
    
    uint8_t odata = *inputImageData;  // Reading the original data

    *inputImageData = 0xAB;  // Writing to input image data for test
    uint8_t readData = *inputImageData;  // Reading back the data

    *outputGrayscaleData = 0x66;  // Setting first byte of output data
    *(outputGrayscaleData + 1) = readData;  // Copying read data to the second byte of output
    *(outputGrayscaleData + 2) = odata;  // Copying original data to the third byte of output

    return 0;
}


A hex file of a PNG image is mapped onto compiler memory at 0x40000000. However, I can't seem to read the data from the said address no matter what I try. I've tried de-referencing pointer to the address and it will always show up as 00 and nothing else. I've tried different types to see if it's the issue with address size but none of them seem to be successful at reading values loaded in the address in Keil MDK. Is there specific way to effectively read values from memory in KEIL MDK ARM V7? Thank you for your help!

If you are able to dereference the pointer without a crash, that to me indicates that something is working. Try to read a larger section of bytes and write them to a file - maybe the first few bytes simply happen to be zero?

Welcome to SO. What is "compiler memory"? What memory is located at that address? Where did you get that address from?

i will try larger section of bytes, but one that's supposed to be in 0x40000000 is 89(hexadecimal) not 00.

compiler memory is just memory i think. i think it's memory used by keil mdk. It gets stored in that address because it was set up that way in the setting.
